# Settings error when converting from .net 4 to .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, settings

I change a settings file programmatically and save the changes:

```
My_Settings.Default["BooleanProperty"] = false;
My_Settings.Default.Save();
```

It works fine as long as I used .NET 4.

When I convert the project to .NET 3.5 I get the following error:

```
"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler to MyApp.My_Setting  
Could not load file or assembly for 'System version = 4.0.0.0'...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does the web.config says on assemblies element?

Comment: Common mishap, your App.config file still contains "4.0.0.0"

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks, what should I do? change it manually to 2.0.0.0?